# Google spreadsheet apis: API to Add/Update a row in particular worksheet using worksheetid

Tags: api, spreadsheet

I am searching for rest API where in I can add/update a row in perticular worksheet. The rest API of V4 version takes spreadsheetID and adds the row in default(first) worksheet.However I want to write a script to add/update a row in worksheet using worksheetID.

Please help
Thanks,

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible using the worksheetID only the name or position.

Answer (score 0):

don't know if you have found your answer, but you can update/insert particular doc spreadsheet.

First get the info about the document

```
const GoogleSpreadsheet = require('google-spreadsheet');
const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(spreadsheetKey);    
const info = await Promise.promisify(doc.getInfo)();
```

After this you can go through all the lists and update your own.

```
const sheetName = "your name of the sheet"    
for (let sheet of info.worksheets) {            
      if(sheet.title === sheetName){
          //do the rest of addRow etc.
      }
    }
```

Have a nice day